# R find count of values in vector x which are greater than values in vector y

Tags: r, vector, comparison

Suppose there are two vectors

```
x = c(20,30,50)
```

and

```
y = c(25,40,60).
```

Objective is to find the number's in x which are greater than numbers in y .

So here it will be 2 as 30 > 25 and 50 > 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `outer` to do comparison of each element of 'x' with that of 'y', get the `colSums` and get the count of numbers that are greater than 0 with `sum`

```
sum(colSums(outer(x, y, `>`)) > 0)
```

Comment: `sum(apply(outer(x, y, ">"), 2, any))`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to define a `dataframe` with the vectors

```
y <- data.frame(y=c(25,40,60,11))
x <- data.frame(x=c(20,30,50,12))
```

> Then you can do an easy comparison and retrieval as shown below

```
> y[y<x]
[1] 11

> y[y>x]
[1] 25 40 60
```

Comment: In his example the values did not need to be in the same position in the two vectors. Also, you do not need to convert vectors to data.frames in order for what you are doing to work.